# Mathematica - distance between two curves

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, distance

I am trying to compute the distance between these two curves. I have tried it like this `FindMinimum[Norm[f[x] - q[x]], {x, 0.2}]`, but according to the automatic evaluation of my university this is incorrect.

```
a = 1.99435 
r = 1
f[x_] := Cos[Sqrt[8 Pi*ArcSin[x]]] + a 
q[x_] := -r*Sin[ArcCos[(x - 1)/r]] + 1.5;
```

Here's a picture:[image: blue -> f[x], orange -> q[x]]
blue -> f[x], orange -> q[x]

Comment: do you want the min vertical distance or the actual minimum distance? (hint)